# bootstrap lable and id display error

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead

I have a jason complex object containing, first name, last name, middkle name, FH name and agent ID. I am uisng bootstrap-typehead for making an ajax call to fetch results. User can enter either first name, last name or agent id. I wouldl ike to show all above fields as lables and agent Id as id. I am geting undefined error.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/6/)

```
 $('#selectAgent').typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {
    objects = [];
    map = {};
    var data = [{"AgentID": 3456,"FName": "Gary", "LName": "Means","MName": "K","FHName": "GaryFH Name"}, {"AgentID": 2050,"FName": "Kevin", "LName": "Mortha","MName": "V","FHName": "Keving FH Name"},{"AgentID": 5678,"FName": "Mike", "LName": "Hundt","MName": "","FHName": "Mike FH Name"}] // Or get your JSON dynamically and load it into this variable

    $.each(data, function (i, object) {
        map[object.label] = object;
        objects.push(object.Fname + object.LName );
    });
    console.log(objects);
    process(objects);
},
updater: function (item) {
    $('id').val(map[item].AgentID);
    return item;
}
});
```

//Console log

LOG: undefinedMeans,undefinedMortha,undefinedHundt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution to your problem, it's case sensitivity. You'll see that you happen to be referencing `Fname` and not `FName`. In practise it's best to dispose of any irregular capitalisation like this, just makes maintaining code easier. In terms of filtering for both agentId and names, this is slightly more difficult but I think you'll find the solution here suitable.

I would pass the whole user record around though that would require you to define sorting and all sorts that is already there for you if it's normal alphanumerical items. Gonna try and get it working by passing along to prototype, if I do I'll update.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwMz2/)

Looked into passing the sorting calls back to the typeahead library but the overhead just isn't worth it. Hope the above is enough!

Comment: It seems I can work for me. I am little confused how it is goling to work when i use ajax call to server to get the results. Is there anyway I can show names that starts with input letter or number ? instead of matching anywhere in the name?

Comment: i don't want to make a call untill user eneters at least 3 characters.

Comment: Use the matcher function to work with custom selection. I've updated the fiddle to only match on queries of over 3 characters in length, for your other requirements you'll just have to be creative in the matcher function. Also, ajax should work just as it would normally, I assume you know how to do that from your comment in the OP?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am new bee for bootstrap-type head. If you can show me a sample of how to make ajax call by adding selected Agent id as query parameter, I really appreciate.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve for me? What do you actually want to do with your agent? I'm struggling to figure out exactly what you want.

Comment: Some reason fiddle is not working.Looking at typehead api, don't you think we can pass "minLength" as argument .

Comment: The fiddle is working for me? Type 'gar' and you'll see gary suggested. Then once selected, click the check input button and you'll get an alert with his agentId.

Comment: Sure. 1. Search by first name,last name or agent id using auto complete.2 When searching by anyone one of those, display Full name in the label field. When User click add button of selected agent show the selected as read only. User able to search and add two agents.Finally when submit, I need to submit those two agent id's to the server. I will have to write another ajax function that postes to the serve ralong with agentid's. Looking for a sample Please see my other post and see the fiddle attched to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750535/converting-to-typehead.

Comment: I tried again. I can see you have added new matcher function, but when i type gar, i am not geting any suggetions.

Comment: I'm just going to edit the JSFiddle to support what you've just commented, though [this](http://imgur.com/sh1un4O) is a link to a screenshot from my computer. I've tried it on firefox safari and chrome so there shouldn't be any reason it's not working with you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44176/discussion-between-lawrence-jones-and-user3067524)

Comment: Right, got it. IE9 doesn't have support for the `__proto__` field and therefore won't have anything to call in the `matching` function. Rewrite the matching function to be your own custom function and you'll find it should work.